# using express with create-react-app doesn't need to call app.get()?

Tags: reactjs, express

I made a tiny web app and tried to deploy it by following the instruction of [Official Tutorial](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment). I ran `npm run build` successfully, then I copied the `index.js` from the tutorial and modified a little bit:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const auth = require('basic-auth'); // A

app.use(express.static('./build'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    const credentials = auth(req); // B
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(9000);
```

where line A and B are for checking authorization. When launching the server by `node index.js`, visiting `localhost:9000` could receive the built `index.html` as expected. However, the line B was not processed at all. I had no idea what's going on, so I tried to remove the whole app.get call and launch the server again:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('./build'));

app.listen(9000);
```

Surprisingly, everything still worked normally when visiting `localhost:9000`. Is it the correct behavior?

P.S. I find a feasible workaround: Rename the `build/index.html` file as , says `build/index2.html`, and call

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './build', 'index2.html'));
```

instead. Is the file `index.html` special to express?